# Reference request: Introduction to stochastic control theory

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-calculus, textbook-recommendation

I’m looking for a nice readable introductory text to stochastic control theory. Background wise, I know some general stochastic analysis and deterministic optimal control theory.

Some criterion I’m looking for, in decreasing order of importance are:

1. Good supply of intuition and examples.
2. Not overly long/detailed/general.
3. Mostly rigorous proofs.

I know of the book *Applied Stochastic Control of Jump Diffusions* by Oksendal, but am not sure if I can gauge how well it satisfies (1) and (2).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-55123-2 fit the bill?

Comment: I also like trawling arXiv for lecture notes, where I found https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02523.pdf (by two well-known researchers in that field).

Comment: These look pretty good, thanks!

Comment: You may like the book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387987231